# How do I remove Feed link in RSS Viewer Web Part?

Tags: web-part, 2007, rss

I hope this is an easy fix in either the XSL or a Content Editor Web Part.  I want to remove/hide the link to the Feed XML from my RSS Viewer Web Part.  IT is for an Intranet page and the people viewing the feed will not need the XML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove it by removing a line in the XSL editor.  The line was:

```
 <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(channel/link))}">
        <xsl:value-of select="channel/title"/>
</a>
```

Then replace it with `<a></a>`

Comment: Worked great - there is a bit of a space where the title was, but does the trick...
thanks!